# Executing cmd command using Maven

Tags: maven, batch-file

I want to execute this command:

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Using Maven. I have to execute this command in the Android SDK/ tools directory. Can anyone help me on how to do this? I think this can be done using batch file but I am not sure how to create a batch file. I need this command to be executed when I type "mvn clean install". Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Executing commands using Maven

You can use the [**Maven Exec Plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) bound to the `install` phase.

In the snippet below, the commant `ping` with the argument `8.8.8.8` will be executed every time you do a `mvn install`:

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>My Command Runner</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>ping</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>8.8.8.8</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

And that's it.

---

### Update:

I see now what you really having trouble with is executing **zipalign**, not an arbitrary command. For that, there are two ways.

#### Using the built-in zipalign of the maven-android-plugin

As of release 2.5.0 of the Android Maven Plugin the `zipalign` goal is part of the plugin. To activate simply add the goal `zipalign` as an execution (e.g. to the `package` phase) and set the `skip` parameter in the `plugin` `configuration` to `false`:

```
<zipalign><skip>false</skip></zipalign>
```

**Full `<plugin>` tag example:**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
                <sign>
                        <debug>false</debug>
                </sign>
                <zipalign>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</inputApk>
                        <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk
                        </outputApk>
                </zipalign>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>alignApk</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Sources:

- [Here you'll find an example](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/zipalign-config-project1/plugin-config.xml) using the an older version (still called `android-maven-plugin`);
- [ZipalignAPKBuiltByMAven](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ZipalignAPKBuiltByMAven): Describes how to automatically zipalign an APK that has been built by Maven.
- [Simpligility](http://www.simpligility.com/2010/06/maven-android-plugin-with-zipalign-and-improved-verification/): Maven Android Plugin with zipalign and improved verification
- Another example: [A full `pom.xml` that uses the `zipalign`](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/pom.xml?spec=svn1159&r=1159).

#### Zipalign using Exec-Maven Plugin

The code below will bind the functionality of zip aligning to the `package` phase, overwriting previous zip aligned file without asking.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>zipalign</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/zipalign</executable>
                 <arguments>
                    <argument>-f</argument>
                    <argument>4</argument>
                    <argument>target/${project.build.finalName}.apk</argument>
                    <argument>target/${project.build.finalName}-zipped.apk</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please note that this profile has to be added to the pom for the actual APK. You can't add it to a parent pom. The reason for this is that it uses the Maven property that defines the artefact name (`project.build.finalName`).

Comment: I tried it but still it is not zip aligned. What will be the name of the new zip-aligned plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an Android project with Maven, you should be using the [maven-android-plugn](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin), which supports the zipalign tool directly.

Comment: is maven-android-plugin the same as android-maven-plugin? Im using android-maven-plugin in my pom.xml

Comment: yes, it was renamed. android-maven-plugin is the new name as of 3.0